# How to serialize JSON object in custom getter?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to get this json from class `User`:

```
{
    "id" : "1234",
    "campaignId" : {
        "campaignId" : "whatever"
    }
}
```

This is the class:

```
class User {

    private String id;
    private String campaignId;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getCampaignId() {
        return "{ \"campaignId\" : \""+ campaignId +"\" }";
    }

}
```

But I have a wrong json:

```
{
    "id" : "1234",
    "campaignId" : "{
        \"campaignId\" : \"whatever\"
    }"
}
```

As you see, first level campaignId is a string instead of an object containing a campaignId key.

How can I achieve that without creating another POJO?

Comment: Try to use a library like GSON to do that

Comment: another thing, why do you want "campaignId" twice? does this make sense ?

Comment: You could use a custom serializer, but that looks a bit bulky to me.

Comment: @SauloAires External API expects JSON with that format. It doesn't make sense to me either...

Comment: Ok, I did it returning Map<String, String> instead of String and it worked properly. I will post it as answer

Comment: I appreciate the accept ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get this json from class User: ...
>
> "campaignId" : {
>          "campaignId" : "whatever"

...

> private String campaignId;

Those things simply don't go together.

If your requirement is that campaignId should be a nested structure, like a map, then **model** it accordingly.

In other words: the type in your "bean" should be something else than `String`. For example, a map. Or maybe, some self-written class that has a single member being a string.

Anything else is just very confusing for your readers. Your code should communicate your intent. And a field that is a string isn't a map.

Its like saying: "look here, my cute cat", where in reality, you have a dog, but you force him into a kitten-costume to look like a cat.

Comment: Disclaimer: no animals were harmed for the production of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

I solved returning Map instead of String:

```
public Map<String, String> getCampaignId() {
    Map<String, String> c = new HashMap<>();
    c.put("campaignId", campaignId);
    return c;
}
```

That's working but if anybody knows how can be done using Jackson annotations or another more elegant solution, I will accept.